# Drop down menu with collection_select: Dividing the dropdown into sections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a dropdown menu for locations, which pulls location data from the DB.

```
@locations
```

...is an ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy object, containing various locations (i.e. loc1, loc2, locY)

What I would really like to do is to have the dropdown divide the locations based on categories (e.g. Numbered Locations: loc1, loc2; Lettered Locations: locY, etc.).

The code thus far is (in a slim file),

```
f.collection_select :location_id, current_provider.locations.except_unassigned, :to_s, { include_blank: true }, class: 'form-control'
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to start?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use grouped_options_for_select and achieve this.

```
<% locations = {'Numbered Locations' => ['loc1', 'loc2'],'Lettered Locations' => ['locX', 'locY'] } %>

<%= select_tag :city, grouped_options_for_select(locations) %>
```

Comment: I would prefer to create a constant in the model and use it in the view file to avoid creating a new string every time

Comment: Thanks for the replies @RaviMariya @AnithaNarayanasamy!

Comment: Actually, now I'm encountering a different error...
When I use select_tag, 
I can no longer access the current_city.city_id attribute.
The output is nil...

Am I doing something wrong??